# Why this function return undefined?

Tags: javascript

I don't undetstand why the following function doesn't return {bar:"hello"} and instead it returns undefined.

```
function foo2() {
    return
    {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}
```

Comment: There's a carriage return after `return` and before the opening brace. Try `return {` instead.

Comment: You might want to read up on [automatic semicolon insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because its compiled to the below because of javascript's auto semi-colon insertion.

```
function foo2() {
    return; // notice the semi-colon here?
    {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}
```

And since `return;` is called, the function terminates without going to the next line of code.
To make it work correctly just put the opening bracket right after `return` as in `return {`

You'd be better off by using semi-colons than omitting them. Want reasons? check out [Dangers of Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion](http://cjihrig.com/blog/the-dangers-of-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion/)

Comment: Note that this is the *exact* example for the dangers of ASI that is shown in pretty much every JS tutorial, styleguide, book, etc. ever created in the history of JS. Anybody who has spent even 3 seconds learning JS knows this.

Comment: Well, _maybe_ four seconds... :-)

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon is inserted after `return` by JS engine.

```
function foo2() {
    return;
    {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}
```

Change to this is ok

```
function foo2() {
    return {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}
```

About **auto semicolon insertion**, aka **ASI**, you may want to read [**this**](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#asi), [**this**](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding) and [**this**](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).